# jQuery, if var = 1 do THIS

Tags: jquery

The code below populates a disabled form field with the contents of another field as the user types in it.

The disabled form field is enabled when 'edit' is clicked, and shows two more options 'cancel' and 'save'.

Upon clicking 'edit' the variable 'counter' is set to = 1

Here is where I am falling short...

If the counter == 1 then the auto population of the newly enabled field should be halted.

However, despite the counter variable being updated the auto-population is still active.

Any ideas?

[**JSfiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mfDug/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 0
$('#filename_edit').click(function(){
    $('#filename').prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).hide();
    $('#filename_edit_btns').show();
    counter = 1;
    alert(counter);
});
$('#filename_edit_cancel').click(function(){
    $('#filename').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $('#filename_edit').show();
    counter = 0;
    alert(counter);
});
$('#filename_edit_save').click(function(){
    $('#filename').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $('#filename_edit').show();
    counter = 1;
    alert(counter);
});
if (counter == 0) {
    $('#title').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {  
        var myStr = $(this).val()
            myStr=myStr.toLowerCase();
            myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g,"");
            myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "-");

        $('#filename').val(myStr);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: your if statement only runs once. If you want it to run every time count updates, wrap it in a function that you execute every time you update count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you don't want the *filename* field auto-populated when edit is on.

But you bind your function at page load, so even if the `counter` changes, the bind is still on, and the function will trigger.

One solution is to move your test into the bind :

```
$('#title').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {          
    if (counter == 0) {                              //<--- Here
        var myStr = $(this).val();
        myStr=myStr.toLowerCase();
        myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g,"");
        myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
        $('#filename').val(myStr);
    }
});
```

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfDug/2/)

Comment: Perfect, great explanation. knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is executed once, you can move it to the handler's body:

```
$('#title').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {  
    if ( counter === 1 ) return;
    var myStr = $(this).val()
        myStr=myStr.toLowerCase();
        myStr=myStr.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g,"");
        myStr=myStr.replace(/\s+/g, "-");

    $('#filename').val(myStr);
});
```